# How to create a database on MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I add my ip to white list and type the command on my mac terminal:

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.vcwmp.mongodb.net/movietogo" --username motogod19
```

then shows the info:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.2
Enter password: 
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017/movietogo?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=atlas-fdputk-shard-0&ssl=true
2020-08-31T16:48:10.763+0800 I  NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for atlas-fdputk-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017
2020-08-31T16:48:10.763+0800 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017
2020-08-31T16:48:10.763+0800 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017
2020-08-31T16:48:10.763+0800 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017
2020-08-31T16:48:11.851+0800 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Confirmed replica set for atlas-fdputk-shard-0 is atlas-fdputk-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("06519e67-e738-44fa-a31d-697c845949f7") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.8
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
MongoDB Enterprise atlas-fdputk-shard-0:PRIMARY>
```

But when I open my browser, I can't any collection or database I can select.

[image]

Just type the command on terminal is wrong ?

Comment: In the Mac terminal you are connected via mongo shell; do a `show dbs` and `show collections` to see your data (see [Mongo Shell reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/mongo-shell/index.html#command-helpers)). The same dtabases and collections should show in your web client. Initially, there will not be any databases or collections - unless you create them.

Comment: Thanks,  I will try to use robo3T connect to MongoDB Atlas.